# How to write an ImmutableList<Number> to a file?

Tags: java, file-io, guava

This should be pretty simple, but it takes about a minute to write about 40 MB.  There's got to be a better way. I imagine there's a lot of hangup on casting the Number to a double, but I'm not sure if that's where the problem lies.  What's the fastest way to write an `ImmutableList<Number>` to a binary file of doubles?

```
public static void multiDoubleToImgFastForSO(String outFilename, ImmutableList<ImmutableList<Number>> arrays) {
        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        
        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(outFilename);
            dos = new DataOutputStream(fos);
            
            for (ImmutableList<Number> array : arrays) {
                
                for (Number number : array) {
                    dos.writeDouble(number.doubleValue());
                }
            }
            
            dos.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why you do that? ImmutableList is Serializable already.

Comment: is your program having enough heap? Is swapping happening?

Comment: Don't use Data Input/Output Streams. These are Java only, and have essentially be superseded by XML and JSON

Comment: Try adding a `BufferedOutputStream` between the two streams, to see if that improves throughput.

Comment: @Andreas is that to say that you wouldn't expect an approach like this to take so long?  I had suspected there was some operation in this that was unexpectedly slow, but is the approach generally sound?

Comment: Just tested on my machine, and adding `BufferedOutputStream` changes performance from 18 seconds to 0.18 seconds.

Comment: @Andreas I had a similar boost to performance myself.  I did not expect that magnitude of improvement!

Comment: @ControlAltDel Data Input/Output Streams are for reading/write primitive Java datatypes from/to a stream in a **portable way**, so says the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html). I think you're confusing the *Data* Input/Output Streams with the *Object* Input/Output Streams.

Comment: @Andreas I am not confused. And your description of Input/Output streams is incorrect. They are really only for writing/reading binary or text data. There are no facilities built into Input/Outputstream for writing a double directly for example.

Comment: The DataInput/OutputStreams were specifically developed to deal with the endian problem (which largely doesn't exist anymore): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @ControlAltDel Seems you didn't read my comment correctly. The `DataInputStream`/`DataOutputStream` "lets an application read/write primitive Java data types from/to an input/output stream in a portable way" (quoted javadoc). They specifically have a method for reading/writing a `double` value, so why you say they don't have a facility for that is beyond me. They specifically use big-endian aka network byte order, to be portable, so they are specifically *not Java only*. --- In contrast, `ObjectInputStream`/`ObjectOutputStream` uses a Java-specific format, so they are Java only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When working with large amounts of data, it is recommended to use buffered i/o streams, so the following update should increase performance.

Also, the code snippet above needs to use `try-with-resources`

```java
try (DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(
    new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outputFilename), 16_000)
)) {
    for (ImmutableList<Number> array : arrays) {
        for (Number number : array) {
            dos.writeDouble(number.doubleValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're going to use Java 7 features (like try-with-resources), you should also use the newer NIO.2 classes, so replace `new FileOutputStream(outputFilename)` with `Files.newOutputStream(Paths.get(outputFilename))`.

Comment: Holy crap.  10 minutes to 3 seconds.  I'm truly astonished at how significant a change that is!  Thanks.  And just to clarify, try-with-resources just means adding that declaration of dos as an argument to try, and doing it that way means I don't have to close it because it handles it as part of the block?

Comment: @FrankHarris, yes, `try-with-resources` implicitly imlement `finally` block where the method close of autocloseable resource is called.